# yocto bitbake: running bitbake python task with python command line options

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake

Is there a way to run bitbake task with python command line options ?
Example:
I have **debug** in the code, and the **debug** is always True, is there a way to pass an python option like python -O when executing bitbake task.

```
python do_some_task(){
    if __debug__:
        print("...")
    ...
  }
addtask do_some_task
```

I'm running my task's in the following way:

```
bitbake -c some_task ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  Python tasks are eval/exec by the worker directly, not by spawning a new instance of python.

For debugging can't you just use bb.debug() and read the task logs, which is where debug output goes?

Comment: I don't want just to log some info, I won't to skip a pice of code that does a commit to the SVN. So when other guys do testing on the code, they can pass in a parameter (or something) and eg. add list will be logged and commit won't be done. 
The other solution, would be to make separate dbg. functions/tasks.

Comment: Use a variable you set in local.conf.  ie DEBUG_MYSTUFF="1" in local.conf and then skip if d.getVar("DEBUG_MYSTUFF")=="1".

Comment: I use the same thing, only whit the True and False.
I was hoping to get a solution with parameter from the terminal when calling the task.